# Create user only by admin

Tags: php, lumen

I am trying to make an application to generate an api token using Lumen for user.

I made login and registration but I want only admin to be able to create create an user. Can anyone point me at the right direction?

Here is my code:

UserController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller {
    /**
     * Register new user
     *
     * @param $request Request
     */
    public function register(Request $request) {
        $hasher = app()->make('hash');
        $username = $request->input('username');
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $password = $hasher->make($request->input('password'));
        $register = User::create([
            'username' => $username,
            'email' => $email,
            'password' => $password,
        ]);
        if ($register) {
            $res['success'] = true;
            $res['message'] = 'Success register!';
            return response($res);
        } else {
            $res['success'] = false;
            $res['message'] = 'Failed to register!';
            return response($res);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get user by id
     *
     * URL /user/{id}
     */
    public function get_user(Request $request, $id) {
        $user = User::where('id', $id)->get();
        if ($user) {
            $res['success'] = true;
            $res['message'] = $user;

            return response($res);
        } else {
            $res['success'] = false;
            $res['message'] = 'Cannot find user!';

            return response($res);
        }
    }
}
```

LoginController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

class LoginController extends Controller {
    /**
     * Index login controller
     *
     * When user success login will retrive callback as api_token
     */
    public function index(Request $request) {
        $hasher = app()->make('hash');
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $password = $request->input('password');
        $login = User::where('email', $email)->first();
        if (!$login) {
            $res['success'] = false;
            $res['message'] = 'Your email or password incorrect!';
            return response($res);
        } else {
            if ($hasher->check($password, $login->password)) {
                $api_token = sha1(time());
                $create_token = User::where('id', $login->id)->update(['api_token' => $api_token]);
                if ($create_token) {
                    $res['success'] = true;
                    $res['api_token'] = $api_token;
                    $res['message'] = $login;
                    return response($res);
                }
            } else {
                $api_token = sha1(time());
                $create_token = User::where('id', $login->id)->update(['api_token' => $api_token]);
                $res['success'] = true;
                $res['api_token'] = $api_token;
                $res['message'] = $login;
                return response($res);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Authenticate Middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory as Auth;

class Authenticate {
    /**
     * The authentication guard factory instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new middleware instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Auth $auth) {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @param  string|null $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null) {
        if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->has('api_token')) {
                $token = $request->input('api_token');
                $check_token = User::where('api_token', $token)->first();
                if ($check_token == null) {
                    $res['success'] = false;
                    $res['message'] = 'Permission not allowed!';

                    return response($res);
                }
            } else {
                $res['success'] = false;
                $res['message'] = 'Login please!';

                return response($res);
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think what I understood from your post is you want only a logged in admin user be able to Register a new user in the system.

Comment: If that is the case why not verify the logged in user in the 'Register User' module and create only if an admin user token is found

Comment: thank you sir, im new in laravel or lumen and im using postman to get api token and im still kinda confused how lumen with postman works so if i do the method youre suggesting do i need to login with admin user first to get registration working or i just need to copy and paste the admin token to postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a middleware for adminrole authentication

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Adminrole
{



    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        $admin = $this->auth->getUser();

        if(!ADMIN) {
            return response()->json(['success'=> false,'error' => 'Invalid Admin User'])->setStatusCode(400);
        }  

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Then register the middleware in routeMiddleware from bootstrap/app.php

```
$app->routeMiddleware([

    'admin' => App\Http\Middleware\Adminrole::class,

]);
```

Add you middleware to the registration api-url route

```
$api->post('YOUR-URL', [
        'uses' => 'UserController@register',
        'middleware' => 'admin'
    ]);
```

Comment: why thank you so much sir but it seems like i got an error saying Undefined property: App\Http\Middleware\Adminrole::$auth

Comment: Did you call the auth object in your middleware? that is same like Default Authenticate Middleware   `use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory as Auth;`

Comment: yes did sir

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory as Auth;

Comment: And did you add this?
`protected $auth;
 public function __construct(Authentication $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }`

Comment: whoops, i just did and now i got another error saying 

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::getUser() in C:vendor\illuminate\auth\AuthManager.php on line 294

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::getUser()

Comment: Lets get the user details from `$this->auth->user()` and find the user role to check

Comment: did you mean my user model?

this is my auth.php if it helps
<?php

return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => env('AUTH_GUARD', 'api'),
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'api' => ['driver' => 'api'],
    ],


    'providers' => [
        //
    ],


    'passwords' => [
        //
    ],

];

Comment: I meant it from middleware `$this->auth->user()` using this code you can get the user details to check the user is admin or not